# matrix multiplication using pointers in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int mul(int *a[3][3], int *b[3][3]);

int i,j,k,*c[3][3],*a[3][3],*b[3][3];

int main()
{
    printf("enter the elements of 1st 3*3 matrix:A");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("enter the elements of 1st 3*3 matrix:B");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    mul(a,b);
    printf("result=");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("\t%d\t",*c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int mul(int *a[3][3], int *b[3][3])
{
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            *c[i][j]=0;
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                c[i][j] = *a[i][k] * *b[k][j] + *c[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to do matrix multiplication using pointers but I am not getting any result.

I searched on google but cannot understand any of them.

also any of them were far different  than mine.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

When manually multiplying matrices with pointers, you might want to represent them as one single `array[]`, instead of a vector of `array[]`'s.

This way, it is easier to move the pointers. Consider [this implementation](https://tavianator.com/a-quick-trick-for-faster-naive-matrix-multiplication/):

```
void matmul(double *dest, const double *lhs, const double *rhs,
            size_t rows, size_t mid, size_t cols) {
    memset(dest, 0, rows * cols * sizeof(double));
 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        const double *rhs_row = rhs;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < mid; ++j) {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < cols; ++k) {
                dest[k] += lhs[j] * rhs_row[k];
            }
            rhs_row += cols;
        }
        dest += cols;
        lhs += mid;
    }
}
```

Comment: vector is C++ though

Comment: Thanks, changed to `array` to prevent this misinterpretation

Answer (score 0):

There's two main things going on here:

1. When you declare a pointer, e.g. `int* x`, this creates a global variable to store the *location* of an array of ints, but it does not create the actual array of ints themselves.  If you just make that declaration and then do `*x = 0;`, you will get a segfault (probably).  Actually creating the array requires allocating memory with a call to `malloc`.  [This article](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation) describes the basics.
2. Multi-dimensional array types are a little funny in C when you use pointers. The way I generally write such code is by representing a matrix as type `int**`.  A value `x` of type `int**` is a pointer to a pointer to a value.  You can write `x[2][3]` to get the value of the 2nd row/3rd column of the matrix, and similarly assign using `x[1][0] = 5` (for example).

Therefore, I would change the declarations at the beginning to be:

```
int mul(int** a, int** b);
int i,j,k,**c,**a,**b;
```

Then I would write a function to allocate a 3x3 matrix.

```
int** alloc_matrix(int rows, int cols)
  int** matrix = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*rows);
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*cols);
  }
  return matrix;
}
```

Then your main function looks like

```
int main() {
  a = alloc_matrix(3,3);
  b = alloc_matrix(3,3);
  c = alloc_matrix(3,3);
  ...
```

You also need to remove the extra dereference operator `*` in several places to make this work.  That's a homework problem for you :-)

There are also other ways to do this, but this is the most intuitive solution using pointers to me.  You can also do this without pointers at all, by just statically allocating `a`, `b`, and `c` as 3x3 arrays.